# How to get rectangle with straight border right top radius?

Tags: html, css

how to make a rectangles:

1. First with top right radius straight not rounded?
2. Second with left bottom radius straight not rounded?

Below image:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this solution might come in handy? Similar question to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215870/css-full-diagonal-transparent-corner-cut-on-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following by using the `clip-path`.
You can simply make triangle clip path then positioned where you want to make that edge the give it the same background color as container to make it transparent

### Here is an example

```css
.box.n1,
.box.n2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box.n1 {
  background: red;
}

.box.n2 {
  background: blue;
}

.box.n1::before,
.box.n2::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.box.n1::before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 0, 0 100%);
}

.box.n2::before {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box n1"></div>
<div class="box n2"></div>
```